# Assigning different value for each row of the array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make some changes for my project but I have an issue when I want to change the score value depending on which row I hit with the ball. If you hit the first row the score to increase with 5, if you hit the second row the score to increase with 10 and if you hit the third row the score to increase with 15. I'm using two dimensional array for my brick rectangle public **int map [][];**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Starting the timer.
    timer.start();
    // The brain of the game.
    if(play) {
        // Detecting intersection between the ball and the paddle.
        if(new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20).intersects(new Rectangle(playerOne, 550, 100, 8))) {
            ballYdir = -ballYdir;
        }

    A:  for(int i = 0; i < map.map.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < map.map[0].length; j++) {
                if(map.map[i][j] > 0) {
                    int brickX = j * map.brickWidth + 80;
                    int brickY = i * map.brickHeight + 50;
                    int brickWidth = map.brickWidth;
                    int brickHeight = map.brickHeight;
                    // Creating a rectangle that will host the bricks.
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                    Rectangle ballRect = new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20);
                    Rectangle brickRect = rect;
                    // Check if the ball intersects with the bricks. If you hit a brick add 5 points to the score, delete the brick from the frame and change the ball's direction.
                    if(ballRect.intersects(brickRect)) {
                        map.setBrickValue(0, i, j);
                        totalBricks --;
                        score += 5;
                        if(ballposX + 19 <= brickRect.x || ballposX + 1 >= brickRect.x + brickRect.width) {
                            ballXdir = - ballXdir;
                        }
                        else {
                            ballYdir = - ballYdir;
                        }
                        break A;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ballposX += ballXdir;
        ballposY += ballYdir;

        // Conditions that make the ball to interact with the borders and to change the ball's direction.
        // Left border.
        if(ballposX < 0) {
            ballXdir = -ballXdir;
        }
        // Top border.
        if(ballposY < 0) {
            ballYdir = -ballYdir;
        }
        // Right border.
        if(ballposX > 670) {
            ballXdir = -ballXdir;
        }
    }
    // Redraw all of the graphic objects.
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted some example data before and after (actual and desired).

Comment: What is the issue? What is working and what is not? Show more code.

Comment: Everything is working I just want to make the pints to be different. If I hit a brick from the first row each brick to have store value 5, if I hit brick from the second row the score value to be 10, if I hit brick from the third row the score value to be 15.